# how to continue a while loop with an open file using os in python3

Tags: python, subprocess

So lets say that i created a while loop where the user inputs a name and it outputs his last name

```
choice = input()
if choice == "Mark":
   print("Zuckerberg")
elif choice == "Sundar":
   print("Pichai")
```

but i want to help the user and when he types "help" a .txt file will open up and as i want it to be an infinite loop its going to be a while...(joke)

```
import os

choice = input()
while True:
    if choice == "Mark":
       print("Zuckerberg")
    elif choice == "Sundar":
       print("Pichai")
    elif choice == "help":
       howto = "notepad.exe howto.txt"
       os.system(howto)
```

as it is is going to run but when you open the file 'choice' is going to stop running resulting to not print out the surnames. if you close the .txt file it will continue but how do i make it work without closing the file?

Thanks in advance

Comment: [`subprocess.Popen(howto)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen)

Comment: @Rawing Are you sure about that? Docs says "Wait for command to complete"

Comment: @Rawing: I think he wants `subprocess.Popen([howto])`.  python will wait for a termination signal to continue when using `call`

Comment: @cricket_007 My bad, I shouldn't be posting at 4am I guess.

Comment: @Rawing i didn't even understand how to use subprocess its an unresolved reference if i put in my code right away

Comment: @mangafas `import subprocess`

Comment: @Rawing yeah sorry it worked... why dont you post it as an answer so it will be easier for people to find the answer?

Comment: @James i think on the duplicate it says that his external command wasn't working right?